# Jupiter notebook to Latex - characters are too big

Tags: overleaf

I tried to import directly my Jupiter notebook to a .tex file (in overleaf) but I don't know how to make the overall size of the code smaller. There is one line in the raw file that would seem to do this task (line 118 `% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line`) but I don't understand how to use it.

EDIT: I will try being more clear about this. I am editing a jupyter notebook using Anaconda Navigator. Using this notebook there is an option to export the code as a ".tex" file. When I do this all the Markdown text is very clean and the size is perfect (it is the normal latex size). The thing I would like to change is the size of the text in the code blocks. It look like they are using a block called `Verbatim` to get the proper code font and background color. And there is the line 118 as mentioned before that has a command that seems to be able to change the size of the code only. I wish I have been more clear on this one. Thank you for your help.
[image: screenshot of the code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be (a lot) more specific about what exactly you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: Mico is obviously spot-on, we need more details. Anyway, the suggestion there seems to be that you must add the text `,fontsize=\small` (including the comma) somewhere. This *somewhere* is the comma-separated list of options that pertains (maybe) to `\documentclass` or to `\bibliography`. Something along the lines of `\documentclass[...,...,fontsize=small,...]{...}`.

Comment: Can you show us the .tex file where you see this comment?

Comment: Could you please edit your title and do `s/Jupiter/Jupyter/g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I mentioned in first version that this appeared to come from Pandoc templates, but it seems to have migrated in the intervening years to [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/) which is used by Jupyter Notebook for conversions under the hood.

More precisely this involves the [base.tex.j2](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/main/share/templates/latex/base.tex.j2) Jinja2 template and [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/6f77b0be07a494af5dcc55fb827ec0cfeb6bbfdd/share/templates/latex/base.tex.j2#L128-L129) is a link to the relevant lines.

Instructions how to use your own template are [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html).

As a user of  Jupyter Notebook workflow you are in the much better position to convert these hints into a solution to your problem than participants of this TeX forum.

The simplest, apart from overriding the template, appears to see if Jupyter documentation mentions a way to add custom material in the LaTeX document preamble.  As mentioned earlier inserting `\fvset{fontsize=\small}` is all you need to achieve.  Beware that backslash needs doubling in Python string literals, or use raw strings.

---

(initial answer)
This is extracted from Pandoc templates, for example you can find a relevant dicussion [there](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2178).

The Verbatim is defined by [fancyvrb](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package.

You are supposed to add the `,fontsize=\small` like this for example (the space after the comma does not matter here, but sometimes spaces matter in LaTeX...)

```latex
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}, fontsize=\small}
```

If it it were in a LaTeX file written manually one would consider `\fvset{fontsize=\small}` in the preamble.